# Special characted incorrectly stored in POSTGRES DB

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, encoding, character-encoding

Project is based on
Postgres database version 9.3.5, 
Java 7, org.hibernate hibernate-core 3.6.10.Final

Problem : 
I have two separate system running the same web application. One on of the systems everything is persisted correctly on the other Strings sent to Postgres database contain unicode characters and text like 'nnés' is persisted as 'nns' or 'nnÃ©s-2' . The only difference I noticed between those two systems Is one displaying UNICODE and the otherUTF8 as client encoding when doing SHOW client_encoding; in the console. The one running unicode works correctly the other does not.

My question is
Is it possible that client encoding got stuck/hardcoded somehow and it is not being selected based on real client encoding which would mean the strings sent in unicode arent converted to UTF8 but just persisted.

What can be the reasons for such a behavior.

Comment: Unicode is not even an encoding to start with...

Comment: Always use UTF8 everywhere. Your current problem shows you that some client is using a different encoding.

Answer (score 0):

try `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: Why would request encoding matter when systems are tested with same string and browser?